# Registering for a domain on Wordpress

Tags: wp-admin, domain

I have recently started development with wordpress for a project and its wonderful! I am following **Wordpress Essential training** on **lynda.com** to help me build a foundation on the subject matter.

I have almost completed customizing the website and would now like to register of a domain, but am not sure how to do this.

I am able to log onto the wp-admin (admin panel) to make customizations, but when I try to log onto the wordpress website (for buying a domain) it says i hve incorrect username/password.

What would be a good route to proceed? **How do I go about registering a domain?**

note: My apologies if I am not following any formatting protocols in this question, it is my first question and I am really trying to learn.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wordpress.com and wordpress.org are two different things. if you're doing theme customizations locally odds are this is WP Platform. wordpress.com ( from my limited understanding ) is just a blog platform that they host, much like blogger and customizations are limited or none. You would go to a host to register a domain for your website. There are **millions** of hosting providers out there. Really it's just doing researching and finding a host your like best for the cost you need. *Usually* the cheaper the hosting the less quality of service they provide so find a middle ground in price.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know if you are using self-hosted WordPress, localhost or wordpress.com.

Read about the differences between WordPress.COM and .ORG: [WordPress.com and WordPress.org — Support — WordPress.com](https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/) to determine the differences and find out your options for registering a domain.

You can register a domain using wordpress.com along with using that service. If self-hosted WordPress, use one of the common domain registrars on the web: http://www.google.com/search?&q=domain+registration